# AJAX post data to DB without ASP:button

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I retrieve a value in js and i want to insert it in the DB with ajax post. Is it possible to do that without asp:button to bind the value to the code behind?

UPDATE here is the Js:

```
function readXML() {
  var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xml.open('GET', 'toXml/file.xml', false);
  xml.send();
  var xmlData = xml.responseXML;
  if (!xmlData) {
    xmlData = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml.responseText, 'text/xml');
  }

  var itemsID = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("entry");
  var itemsTitle = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("entry");
  var itemsCustomer = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("d:Customer");
  var itemsBrand = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("d:Brand");
  var itemsCountries = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("d:Countries");
  var itemsElement = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("d:element");

  var i, k, j, ID, Title, Customer, Brand, Countries;

  var list = [];

  for (i = 0; i < itemsTitle.length; i++) {

    var Brands = "";
    var Country = "";

    itemI = itemsID[i];
    itemT = itemsTitle[i];
    itemCr = itemsCustomer[i];
    itemB = itemsBrand[i];
    itemCs = itemsCountries[i];
    itemEl = itemsElement[k];

    ID = itemI.getElementsByTagName("d:Id")[0].firstChild.data;

    Title = itemT.getElementsByTagName("d:Title")[0].firstChild.data;

    Customer = itemCr.getElementsByTagName("d:element")[0].firstChild.data;

    for (k = 0; k < itemB.children.length; k++) {
      Brand = itemB.getElementsByTagName("d:element")[k].firstChild.data;

      if (k > 1) {
        Brands += Brand + ",";
      }
      else {
        Brands = Brand;
      }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < itemCs.children.length; j++) {
      Countries = itemCs.getElementsByTagName("d:element")[j].firstChild.data;

      if (j > 1) {
        Country += Countries + ",";
      }
      else {
        Country = Countries;
      }

    }
    list[i] = [ID, Title, Customer, Brands, Country];
  }

  var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 200, -1], [10, 25, 50, 200, "All"]],
    data: list,
    columns: [
      { title: "ID" },
      { title: "Title" },
      { title: "Customer" },
      { title: "Brands" },
      { title: "Country" },
      { title: "Check", "defaultContent": "<button class=\"checkBtn\" type=\"button\">Check</button>" },
      { title: "Create", "defaultContent": "<button class=\"createBtn\" type=\"button\">Create</button>" }
    ],
    columnDefs: [{
      "targets": [0],
      "visible": true,
      "searchable": true
    }]
  });

  $('#table_id').on('click', '.checkBtn', function () {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    alert("ID:" + data[0] + "," + "Title:" + data[1] + "," + "Customer:" + data[2] + "," + "Brand:" + data[3] + "," + "Country:" + data[4]);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Selida.aspx/InsertData",
      data: JSON.stringify(data[0]),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {

        alert("all good");
      },
      error: function (errMessage) {
        alert("Error:" + errMessage);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Through C# im getting data and i save it into an xml file. Then with the js i retrieve that data and with Jquery datatables im displaying on the page.

I Have a method in c# called InsertData which is supposed to insert the data in the DB. I think that the problem is in the ajax call.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see a code snippet?

Comment: I updated my question, if you need more info tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, i can post a value from js with an ajax call that has no relation with the server side

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Selida.aspx/CheckData",
      data: JSON.stringify({ trala : data[0] }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {

        alert("It's already in the DB");
      },
      error: function (errMessage) {
        console.log("Error:" + JSON.stringify(errMessage));
      }

    });
```

and the parameter in the c# method must have the name "trala" in order to retrieve the value from the post.